# Execute inline command remote server with ssh

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to create a single script that connects to a remote server and executes an update, but I want to make sure no one is using the machine at the time so I execute a "ps" command to see the process and then prompt if the installation should continue. Here's the code I'm attempting to make:

```
ssh -T root@$machine <<- 'END'
    #Show the non-root processes
    ps -ef | grep -v root

    #Prompt if should continue (this doesn't work)
    echo "Continuar a instalação? [y/n]"
    select valor in y n
    do
        case $REPLY in
            y )
                echo "Digitado y"
                break
                ;;
            n )
                echo "Digitado n"
                exit
                ;;
        esac
    done

    #Test if it's working
    echo "Test"
END
```

When I execute this code, I get the following behaviour:

```
Continuar a instalação? [y/n]
1) y
2) n
#? 1) y
2) n
#? #? 1) y
2) n
#? #? 
#? 1) y
2) n
#? #? #? 1) y
2) n
#? #? #? #?
```

And then the script closes. I tried running ssh with the -t -t option but I still get the same problem. What am I missing?

Comment: remote command execution using ssh will not have a tty assigned to the process. Hence it will not be able to accept input.

Comment: And what can I do about it?

Comment: There are several suggestions [HERE ON THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal). One of them might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to separate the command into two ssh connections, one for listing the processes and other to update, and in the middle of them the prompt to continue:

```
ssh -T root@$machine <<- 'END1'
    ps -ef | grep -v root | grep -v lightdm
END1

echo "Continuar a instalação? [y/n]"
select valor in y n
do
    case $REPLY in
        y )
            break
            ;;
        n )
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done

ssh -T root@$machine <<- 'END2'
    printf "Test\n"
END2
```

The problem is that it'll require you to put the password for the ssh connection twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't communicate with the remote process (`select`), when you put the script on `stdin`. It happens to you that the `select` reads some garbage from your `stdin` and then reads EOF, when your input ends.

You should rather copy the file to the server using `scp` and then run it.